# jQuery form auto-submit upon file input change in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, file-upload

This topic has been covered on this forums, but I haven't found a working IE solution yet (tested 7, 8  & 9). Works fine in other browsers. I hope someone has a solution for it.
Thanks in advance!

**What's this about:**

I want to get rid of the standard file input element so I added an image.
Upon click it shows the browse window. When a file is selected the form is submitted.
Due to browser security I temporarily show the file input element, focus and the hide it.

**The problem:**

IE shows *"Access is denied." jquery.1.7.2.js line 3241, character 6*.
Without the show/hide trick, the problem remains.
When I click on the browse button and choose a file, the form does get submitted.
The problem seems to be that the file browsing action is triggered by another element:

Full code:

```
    $('#fakeupload').click(function(){
        $('#form').show();
        $('#realupload').focus().trigger('click');
        $('#form').hide();          
    });

    $('#realupload').change(function(){
        $('#form').show();
        $('#form').submit();
        $('#form').hide();          
    });
```

Comment: You are definitely pretty close to solving this issue, I've seen it come up quite often with only "it isn't possible" solutions. Have you pinpointed exactly which line from your code is causing the `Access is denied`?

Comment: @KevinB the error is caused by $('#form').submit(); This does work when I use only the 2nd part of the code (realupload).change.

Comment: Do you have some special form handler, or is that submitting to a hidden iframe, or is it submitting to the same page, etc.

Comment: @KevinB nothing fancy really. Standard POST form, submitting to a different URI

Comment: I've got stuck at the exact same problem :-/ , so you did solve as per the accepted answer solution ?

Comment: @Unspecified yes, that seemed to be the best approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This remains an issue that can't be solved. In order for it to work, the browse button must be clicked by the user. The trick here is modifying the browse button so it will fit the image.

Comment: I just want to add to this answer, that you can use CSS to set the opacity of the browse button so the user actually clicks the browse button when they think they click something else. Etc. filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);      filter: alpha(opacity=0);              -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";              opacity: 0;

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 8 is blocking you with 'Access Denied' since a group of no-so-smart people in Microsoft made the decision.

If you try to trigger the click method in an input type file, then later you will have issues in the submit.

This is the only browser that do that kind of stuff.

Thanks again Microsoft, your browser is a "piece of work" >:(

Comment: It's a security thing, and I can perfectly understand why it's not allowed to fake the click. I'm not happy with it, but I can relate. And IE isn't the only one, Chrome has the same "issue".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning permissions for your file to be accessed by the browser?
Did you clear your cache?
Try setting an expiry date?
Try replacing show()/hide() with css("display","block")/css("display","none")

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I really don't think you're going in the right direction.